# OPOS Service Objects for USB Devices

Tags: object, service, usb, scale, opos

I need to implement an OPOS service object for a scale, specifically a USB scale if it is possible. I have read and checked out all documents and sources from [Monroe Consulting Services](http://monroecs.com/index.htm) about OPOS but haven't found any source linking to USB devices. I would like to know if someone out there as implemented OPOS service objects for USB devices. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a few OPOS Service Objects that communicate over a USB Interface; some require hardware convertors (such as a RJ12 -> USB-B) and others can operate under a VCP (Virtual COM PORT).

Curtiss Monroe does provide a CCO (Common Control Object) for an OPOS Scale, so it is definately possible to implement an SO. Also.. what is the manufacturer and model number / hardware ID of the specific device?

Most retailers / hardware vendors provide the specific OPOS Service Objects for you so you may not even need to explicity create one yourself. If you are confident that you do indeed need to create an SO, it's important to consider if the application will use POS For .NET Service Objects or Legacy (UPOS) Service Objects.

Hope this information was useful. A.

Comment: Thank you answer. I appreciate it very much.
I am using Elane USB Parcel scales. I have just created the service object for POS for .NET for this scale and it works well. I think it is really possible to create an OPOS service object as well. It is just that my COM programming experience and knowledge are not good enough. I will check the .NET Assemblies that MCS has provided and see if I can create the corresponding OPOS SO for these USB scales.

Comment: My question is, once you implement a Service object, how it is identified by CO based on device name?